# Probability of transition

Tags: probability

I am confused on how to solve this question.

1) Suppose a light bulb is programmed to turn on and off randomly every 7 seconds such that if the light is currently on the probability it will turn off next is 0.6 and if the light is currently off the probability that it will turn on next is 0.8

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0.4 & 0.6  \\
        0.8 & 0.2  \\        
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The question im confused about is. **Find the probability that after the 3rd transition the light is off, given that the light is currently off.**

This question comes from the study guide for my final exam. The given anser is **0.392**. I dont know how they got that number.

Comment: In every transition, the light can either switch from "on" to "off" or vice versa , or it can keep on/off. You have $8$ possible events, sum up the probabilities of the events with an "off" at the end.

Comment: Since you have shown a transition matrix, you may be expected to know that the transition matrix for a sequence of three transitions is the cube of the matrix for one transition.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the state **on** by 1 and **off** by 0.
Given the transition probability matrix
\begin{equation*}
P=\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1 & 0\\
\hline
1 & p_{11}=0.4 &p_{10}= 0.6\\
0 & p_{01}=0.8 &p_{00}= 0.2
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}
we require the probability  $p_{00}^{(3)}$. The possible transitions from state 0 to 0 in exactly 3 steps are
$$0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0\quad or$$
$$0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 0\quad or$$
$$0\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0\quad or$$
$$0\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 0\quad or$$
whose probabilities are
$$p_{00}\cdot p_{00}\cdot p_{00}$$
$$p_{00}\cdot p_{01}\cdot p_{10}$$
$$p_{01}\cdot p_{10}\cdot p_{00}$$
$$p_{01}\cdot p_{11}\cdot p_{10}.$$
Hence, $$p_{00}^{(3)}=p_{00}\cdot p_{00}\cdot p_{00} + p_{00}\cdot p_{01}\cdot p_{10} + p_{01}\cdot p_{10}\cdot p_{00} + p_{01}\cdot p_{11}\cdot p_{10}.$$
The required probability can also be obtained by computing $P^3$, as suggested by David K, in comments above.